# Amazon webservice without SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I need to use Amazon web service for API gateway, I already implemented Networking part and model classes. After deploying the API, AWS generating iOS SDK with a default Networking client and model classes. Can we use AWS without importing its SDK? any problems? Plz help!!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course, you "can" write all of your own code from scratch -- all of the APIs of all of the Internet-facing services from AWS are fully documented -- but if you're saying you want to use the code they've generated specifically for your API, then, you have to have the dependencies, they've documented.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html